# Working with non ionic-native plugins in Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm using a custom cordova plugin (https://github.com/VJAI/simple-crypto), not available in ionic native.

I'm using Ionic 2 and have installed the plugin using the command:
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/VJAI/simple-crypto`

The interface is like this:

```
var rncryptor = cordova.require("com.disusered.simplecrypto.SimpleCrypto");

rncryptor.encrypt(key, data, successCallback, failureCallback)
rncryptor.decrypt(key, data, successCallback, failureCallback)`
```

Method 1:
I have tried to invoke the plugin using

```
window.plugins.SimpleCrypto.encrypt(...)
```

But when I run `ionic serve`, i get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'SimpleCrypto' of undefined

Method 2:
Another way i tried was

```
cordova.plugins.SimpleCrypto.encrypt(...)
```

The error i got was

> ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

Is there any way to go around doing this?

Comment: not sure about that plugin but check out http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/ . These plugins were made by the Ionic community for use with Angular. Maybe something in the docs will shed light on using a regular cordova plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to use

```
cordova.plugins.SimpleCrypto.encrypt
```

function on your device?

It is working for my case. The reason being, the emulator is unable to run cordova.js

Comment: how come? I got an error: Cannot find name 'cordova'.

Comment: @chipbk10 are u using simplecryto lib? which ionic 2 version u are targeting? U can see those in "package.json"

Comment: My ionic2 is 2.0.0-beta.33, I don't use simplecrypto lib. I use the plugin "cordova-plguin-ms-adal".

Comment: I get the same errors as the original question, and when I try:  `this.encrypter = cordova.plugins.SimpleCrypto;`

I get:

`ERROR in ./app/pages/service/personService.ts
 (304,42): error TS2339: Property 'SimpleCrypto' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'.`

Answer (score 2):

You could try...

```
declare var SimpleCrypto:any;

SimpleCrypto.encrypt(...)
```