# use plugins non ionic-native in Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm using a cordova plugin from github, not available in ionic native.

I have problem. How to use non ionic-native plugins in Ionic 2 ?

I try :

```
declare var myPlugin: any;

myPlugin.doSomething(...)
```

and other forum solutions

but I have error :

```
ReferenceError: myPlugin is not defined
at new HomePage (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:18762:9)
```

My config :

```
Ionic Framework: ^2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic Native: ^2.2.3
Ionic App Scripts: 1.0.0
Angular Core: 2.2.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1
Node: 6.9.5
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
cordova 6.5.0
```

Same problem : 
[Working with non ionic-native plugins in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783081/working-with-non-ionic-native-plugins-in-ionic-2)

Comment: Can you add a link to the plugin you are trying to use?

As suggested in the link that you provided, did you try logging `cordova` to see if the plugin is there?

Comment: are you trying in a device or ionic serve?

Comment: in ionic serve, testing initialize function. I will try in device.

Comment: Same in device "Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: myPlugin is not defined
ReferenceError: myPlugin is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Few things to look:

- Verify if you plugin entry is present in the plugin.xml and package.json files? If not you might need to add an entry as the below example.
- Use the plugin only when the platform is ready.
- Test your app in real device.
- Use "ionic add" instead "cordova add" to add new plugins.

Refer the below thread which might be of some help on editing your plugin.xml file.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-non-native-plugins-on-ionic-2/63936/17

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in plugin.xml `clobbers` is set as `window.plugins.myplugin`.
This makes *window* the global object and you have to declare:

```
declare var window: any;
```

and functions called as:

```
window.plugins.myPlugin.pluginInitialize()
```

or if this is your custom made plugin, you could make clobbers object as `myPlugin`

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this :

First import plugin or library as :

```
import plugin from 'plugin-name' ;
```

And then use :

```
plugin.functionName();
```